# Write to multiple CSV files within Oracle SQL script

Tags: oracle, export-to-csv, sqlplus, utl-file

I have a requirement to generate a series of reports (in csv format) based on data held in an oracle database (v19.20).

The reports are to be generated by running a shell script on a local server which can access the database, which will execute a SQL*Plus command to extract the data.

e.g.:

generateReports.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

function logger() {
        local ts=$(date +%D\ %R:%S)
        echo "${ts}:${0##*/} - ${1}"
        echo "${ts}:${0##*/} - ${1}" >> logs/generateReports.log
}

function prop {
    grep "${1}" database.properties|cut -d'=' -f2
}

function isOracleError(){

countOfORAErrors=`grep "ORA-" logs/ *.log | wc -l`
countOfSP2Errors=`grep "SP2-" logs/ *.log | wc -l`
countofcomplileerrors=`grep "compilation errors" logs/ *.log | wc -l`
 if [[ $countOfORAErrors -gt 0 || $countOfSP2Errors -gt 0 || countofcomplileerrors -gt 0 ]]
    then
        logger "Last Script failed with  $countOfORAErrors : ORA- and $countOfSP2Errors :SP2 Errors,  halting execution"
        exit
    else
        logger "Script Completed Successfuly"
    fi
}

USERID="$(prop 'USERID')"
PASSW="$(prop 'PASSW')"
HOST="$(prop 'HOST')"
PORT="$(prop 'PORT')"
SERVICE="$(prop 'SERVICE')"
TNS_STRING="'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=${HOST})(PORT=${PORT}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=${SERVICE})))'"


sqlplus ${USERID}/${PASSW}@${TNS_STRING} @generateReports.sql</dev/null 2>&1 | tee -a logs/dbScripts.log

logger "######################################################################################################"
logger "Process completed : Successfully. "
logger "######################################################################################################"
exit
```

The number of reports to be generated depends on data held in table "REPORT_CATEGORY", which will be setup as follows:

| CATEGORY_CODE | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| A | Report Category A |
| B | Report Category B |
| C | Report Category C |

For each category code found in the above table, I will need to execute a separate query (filtering on the category value in tables which hold data I need to report on) and write the results to a csv file on the local server where the shell script is being run.
e.g.

- /opt/reports/category_a.csv
- /opt/reports/category_b.csv
- /opt/reports/category_c.csv

Currently this is done using a cursor to loop through the codes, execute a SQL statement and use "utl_file" package to write the CSV output:

generateReports.sql:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET ECHO ON
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK

CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY report_dir AS '/opt/reports';

--##########################################################################################################################

DECLARE
        v_file_handle utl_file.file_type;
        c_category_code report_category.category_code%type;
        CURSOR c_report_category is
                select category_code
                from report_category;

BEGIN
   OPEN c_report_category;
   LOOP 
   FETCH c_report_category into c_category_code; 
      EXIT WHEN c_report_category%notfound;
      v_file_handle:=utl_file.fopen('report_dir',c_category_code||'.csv', 'a');
      -- Execute Generic Query with filter on c_category_code and write results to v_file_handle using utl_file.put_line
      utl_file.fclose (v_file_handle);
   END LOOP; 
   CLOSE c_report_category;

END;
/

--##########################################################################################################################
EXIT
```

Whenever I try to execute this, I am hit with error:

```
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'RDSADMIN.RDS_DDL_TRIGGER2'
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20900: Invalid path used for directory: /opt/reports
ORA-06512: at "RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_TRIGGER_UTIL", line 631
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at line 12
```

It seems that `utl_file` will only permit me to write to directories on the server where the database is being hosted, but I need to write this to the local server.
The alternative appears to be using spool, but I am having difficulty switching off unwanted messages/logging and splitting to multiple files with this approach.

What is the best way to write to multiple CSV files from within the same SQL*Plus execution?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? If it is getting `utl_file` to write to a directory on the client then the answer is it is impossible. If you are trying to use `SPOOL`  then you need to provide [MRE] which describes the problem including: your `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for the sample data; the current script that uses `SPOOL` (note: this should be a minimal example which has been simplified as much as possible) and that the issues/errors are with the output and what the expected output is for that sample data.

Comment: If the question is "What is the best way to write to multiple CSV files from within the same SQL*Plus execution?" then the question is off-topic as the "best" is opinion-based.

Comment: Yes I need to be able to write the output to local machine, so utl_file is ruled out as per what you've stated above. At this stage I can replace "What is the best way..." with "How can I..." (write to multiple csv files within a single SQL*Plus execution). The main problem I'm having is that the filenames are generated dynamically inside a cursor loop, and `SPOOL ON/OFF` is not recognised inside the PLSQL block. Currently it seems the only way to solve this is to extract the report categories into a delimited string, parse it in the shell script and invoke multiple SQLPLus executions instead

Comment: You could do that or you could write a single file and put a delimiter line between the different loops and then split the file based on that delimiter into new files. You may also be able to do something with [`COLUMN ... NEW_VALUE ...`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqpug/COLUMN.html#GUID-643B665F-B134-4A0B-88F7-10400D6D199E) but I don't have SQL\*Plus to hand to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that utl_file will only permit me to write to directories on the server where the database is being hosted.

A `DIRECTORY` object in the database refers to a directory on the database server. The database server has no concept of the directories that can be accessed by any client (and would likely cause huge security issues if it could).

`UTL_FILE` can only write to a file within a `DIRECTORY` object so, yes, it can only write to files on the database server.

> The alternative appears to be using spool, but I am having difficulty switching off unwanted messages/logging and splitting to multiple files with this approach.

Yes, use [`SPOOL filename`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqpug/SPOOL.html#GUID-61492052-ECCB-45C8-AF94-AB9794C60BEA) to start spooling to a file and then `SPOOL OFF` to stop spooling to a file and then you can start spooling to another file.

You can refer to the [SQL*Plus documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqpug/SQL-Plus-command-reference.html#GUID-177F24B7-D154-4F8B-A05B-7568079800C6) and use the [`SET`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-A6A5ADFF-4119-4BA4-A13E-BC8D29166FAE)
and [`COLUMN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqpug/COLUMN.html#GUID-643B665F-B134-4A0B-88F7-10400D6D199E) command (among others) to change how the output is formatted and what is, or is not, displayed.

Comment: Thanks. This explanation of UTL_FILE is enough to rule it out for my requirements. Using SPOOL with multiple dynamically generated filenames is not proving any easier however